# Distribuir conteúdo uniformemente em tabelas com php

Tags: php

montei um algorítimo em php para popular 4 tabelas em html de forma uniforme.

Porém, estou achando meu código um tanto sujo e gostaria de verificar se existe uma forma mais limpa de criar este código.

O que ele faz: Ele recebe um array com nomes e números de ramal, e distribui de forma uniforme em 4 tabelas, não importa a quantidade de números e ramais, se for um número não divisível por 4, ele pega o resto e distribui.

Detalhe: O array é apenas um teste, o resultado vem de um CRUD, que possui um BD.

A utilização das propriedades HTML inline, é apenas teste, no sistema vai ser gerido pelas classes CSS responsáveis.

Então peço que dirijam a atenção exclusivamente ao algorítimo distribuidor de resultados.

Segue o meu array:

```
<?php
$grupos = array(
    'adm' => array(
        0 => array(
            'nome' => 'nome0',
            'ramal' => 'ramal0'
        ),
        1 => array(
            'nome' => 'nome1',
            'ramal' => 'ramal1'
        ),
        2 => array(
            'nome' => 'nome2',
            'ramal' => 'ramal2'
        ),
        3 => array(
            'nome' => 'nome3',
            'ramal' => 'ramal3'
        ),
        4 => array(
            'nome' => 'nome4',
            'ramal' => 'ramal4'
        ),
        5 => array(
            'nome' => 'nome5',
            'ramal' => 'ramal5'
        ),
        6 => array(
            'nome' => 'nome6',
            'ramal' => 'ramal6'
        ),
        7 => array(
            'nome' => 'nome7',
            'ramal' => 'ramal7'
        ),
        8 => array(
            'nome' => 'nome8',
            'ramal' => 'ramal8'
        ),
        9 => array(
            'nome' => 'nome9',
            'ramal' => 'ramal9'
        )
    )
);
```

Código

```
define("DIVISOR", 4); //Número de tabelas
$array_size = count($grupos['adm']); //quantidade de ramais
$qtd_por_tabela = (int) ($array_size / DIVISOR); //quantidade em cada tabela
$resto = ($array_size % DIVISOR); //resto a ser dividido nas tabelas
$y = 0; //contador array

for ($i = 1; $i <= DIVISOR; $i++) {
    echo "<div class=\"tables\"><table>";
    $sobra = $resto > 0 ? 1 : 0;
    for ($x = 1; ($x <= ($qtd_por_tabela + $sobra)); $x++) {
        $tag = "<tr><td>";
        $tag.=$grupos['adm'][$y]['nome'];
        $tag.="</td><td>";
        $tag.= $grupos['adm'][$y]['ramal'];
        $tag.="</td></tr>";
        echo $tag;
        $y++;
    }
    $resto = $resto > 0 ? ($resto - 1) : 0;
    echo "</table></div>";
    echo "\r\n";
}
?>
```

Um pouco de CSS para jogar uma tabela ao lado da outra...

```
<style>
    table,
    table td{
    border: 1px solid #000;
    }
    .tables{
        float: left;
        margin: 10px;
    }
</style>
```

O código imprime o seguinte resultado:

```
<div class="tables">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>nome0</td>
            <td>ramal0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>nome1</td>
            <td>ramal1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>nome2</td>
            <td>ramal2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="tables">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>nome3</td>
            <td>ramal3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>nome4</td>
            <td>ramal4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>nome5</td>
            <td>ramal5</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="tables">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>nome6</td>
            <td>ramal6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>nome7</td>
            <td>ramal7</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="tables">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>nome8</td>
            <td>ramal8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>nome9</td>
            <td>ramal9</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Observação: Ele não indenta assim bonitinho, mas fiz manualmente para facilitar a leitura.
A idéia é alcançar este resultado, mas com um algorítimo mais "limpo".

Alguém sabe como fazer?

Comment: uma sugestão que eu faria: tirar as strings com códigos html do for e popular a tabela direto no html, via servidor mesmo ou via Ajax com JSON

Comment: basicamente seu código fica poluído pela injeção de dados na parte lógica (algo muito ruim no conceito de programação), o que você precisa fazer é retirar isto (como no comentário anterior, popular em um arquivo JSON ou banco de dados), se pretende continuar aconselho a deixar direto no HTML o resultado para minimizar, sem isso não vejo outra maneira =/

Comment: em JSON minimiza os impactoes e podemos auxiliar facilmente nessa parte (ainda será compatível com o helper para cakephp, porque utilizaremos php para carregar o arquivo);

Comment: Pessoal, este array não é criado por mim, ele vem de um banco de dados, o array é apenas um teste, para facilitar o entendimento do formato que os dados são recebidos.
Eu quero idéias para o algorítimo, o resto é apenas uma estrutura de testes, sem depender de BD.

Comment: Assim dá pra simular a estrutura facilmente...

Comment: Só um detalhe: `echo '<div class="tables"><table border="1px" bordercolor="#000000">';` ou `echo "<div class='tables'><table border='$variavelPHP' bordercolor='#000000'>";`

Comment: Pessoal, eu esclareci que o css é apenas para teste. Não se apeguem ao detalhe, quero melhorar o algorítimo php;

Comment: @MarceloAymone acompanhe a discussão sobre a reabertura aqui, e dê sua opinião se achar pertinente: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1903

Comment: O que ocorre, no momento que fiz a pergunta, simplifiquei o problema para poder ter auxílio mais facilmente.
Quanto a quebrar em camadas, isto foi feito, porém não demonstrei aqui pois utilizo um framework, e desta forma abstrai o problema para focar no algorítimo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Existe um Design Pattern Estrutural chamado **Composite** que permite a você abstrair o HTML e construir uma estrutura hierárquica de informações compostas, como numa árvore.

Com o Composite você tem diversos objetos, cada um representando uma ramificação do HTML, essas ramificações podem ou não serem compostas de outros elementos.

Para a resposta não ficar maior do que já vai ficar, não vou postar os códigos aqui e sim todos juntos neste [Gist](https://gist.github.com/brunoaugusto/af1b7b25687fe3945c0d). Também inclusos uma implementação bem simples de um *autoloader* para rodar a Aplicação e um pequeno apelo visual com CSS.

Primeiramente, a estrutura de diretórios bem como os arquivos utilizados:

```
|-index.php
|-Composite\Components
|   |-Composite\Components\AbstractComponent.php
|   |-Composite\Components\Component.php
|   |-Composite\Components\Drawable.php
|   \-Composite\Components\HTML
|     |-Composite\Components\HTML\Cell.php
|     |-Composite\Components\HTML\Row.php
|     \-Composite\Components\HTML\Table.php
```

*"Vamos conhecer agora os nossos participantes"*:

- **AbstractComponent.php**

Essa superclasse, abstrata, define uma interface para todos os objetos que comporão algum elemento, algum nó da estrutura hierárquica, e implementa um comportamento padrão para eles.

A propriedade *AbstractComponent::children* armazena todos os nós-filhos de cada elemento criado, desde que respeitada sua condição de existência, permitindo a renderização em níveis da estrutura.

Essa "condição de existência" é controlada pela propriedade *AbstractComponent::leaf* que determina se um dado objeto é uma ramificação (FALSE) ou uma folha (TRUE). Ramificações podem ser compostas de outros elementos filhos, ao passo que "folhas", não.

> Nesse cenário em específico, a fim de simplificar, estarei considerando as células da tabela como folhas, mesmo que num caso real elas não o sejam.

O método *AbstractComponent::add()* é o que permite efetivamente a Composição ocorrer no sentido de agregar novos objetos uns aos outros.

Observe que nele é feita uma verificação para que objetos definidos como sendo uma "folha" não aceitem novos objetos, disparando uma exceção lógica.

Por fim, mas não menos importante, *AbstractComponent::drawChildren()* oferece aos objetos que representam as ramificações um meio de renderizar todos os elementos neles contidos. Como você poderá ver adiante, objetos "folha" são os únicos que não o utiliza.

- **Component** e **Drawable**

Temos duas interfaces, uma para representar os componentes e outra para representar objetos renderizáveis. Na bem da verdade apenas a interface **Component** poderia ser utilizada, mas, por preferência, eu dividi os comportamentos em duas interfaces tornando **Component** um tipo.

- **Table**, **Row** e **Cell**

Para este exemplo existem objetos para representar apenas três elementos HTML, porém, você pode criar outros conforme sua necessidade, bastando estender a superclasse **AbstractComponent** e implementar o método *Drawable::draw()*. E claro, caso seja necessário caracterizar um elemento como "folha", sobrescrever a propriedade protegida anteriormente descrita.

Tanto **Table** como **Row** são bem simples, apenas envolvem os nós-filhos renderizados através de *AbstractComponent::drawChildren()* pelas tags **<table>** / **</table>** e **<tr>** / **</tr>**, respectivamente.

**Cell**, no entanto, é ligeiramente diferente. Além do fato de, aqui exclusivamente, termos invertido a característica dela de não permitir outros níveis na Composição, sobrescrevemos o construtor para termos uma forma de definir o texto que será escrito na célula.

Normalmente nessa hora viria aquele aviso gigantesco num letreiro de neon dizendo para que, quando sobrescrevendo o construtor de uma superclasse, deve-se reinvocá-lo através de *parent::__construct()*. Porém, isso não é de todo obrigatório nessa Aplicação pois, uma vez que a *flag* *AbstractComponent::leaf* tenha sido sobrescrita, *AbstractComponent::add()* irá disparar a exceção lógica caso seja invocada no contexto de um objeto **Cell**.

Se não invocarmos o construtor, não definirmos que o objeto que sobrescreveu a superclasse é uma folha e ainda assim invocarmos **AbstractComponent::add()** (caramba, conseguimos errar 3 vezes :o), receberíamos um *Fatal Error* pois o método **append()** estaria sendo invocado sem um objeto. Objeto esse, um [ArrayObject](http://www.php.net/ArrayObject), definido justamente no construtor da superclasse ora sobrescrito.

Pelo sim, pelo não, deixemos ele ali. Mal não faz ^_^

Igualmente à **Table** e **Row**, *Cell::draw()* é bem simples, apenas insere o valor recebido pelo construtor, ora armazenado numa propriedade com visibilidade *private* (porque privada é feio :p) entre um par de tags **<td>** / **</td>**

*Mas... E como isso se aplica ao problema?*

Primeiro vamos alterar seu array de entrada para alguma coisa um pouquinho diferente apenas para demonstrar que funciona:

```
$groups = array(
    'Administração' => array(
        0 => array(
            'nome' => 'nome0',
            'ramal' => 'ramal0'
        ),
        1 => array(
            'nome' => 'nome1',
            'ramal' => 'ramal1'
        ),
        2 => array(
            'nome' => 'nome2',
            'ramal' => 'ramal2'
        ),
        3 => array(
            'nome' => 'nome3',
            'ramal' => 'ramal3'
        )
    ),
    'Financeiro' => array(
        4 => array(
            'nome' => 'nome4',
            'ramal' => 'ramal4'
        ),
        5 => array(
            'nome' => 'nome5',
            'ramal' => 'ramal5'
        ),
        6 => array(
            'nome' => 'nome6',
            'ramal' => 'ramal6'
        ),
        7 => array(
            'nome' => 'nome7',
            'ramal' => 'ramal7'
        ),
        8 => array(
            'nome' => 'nome8',
            'ramal' => 'ramal8'
        ),
        9 => array(
            'nome' => 'nome9',
            'ramal' => 'ramal9'
        )
    )
);
```

Apenas quebrei ele para considerar mais de um departamento. Antes de iterar para compor nossa estrutura, temos de definir o elemento principal da mesma, ou seja, a tabela onde cada linha e cada célula será agregada:

```
$tableGroup = new Composite\Components\HTML\Table;
```

Agora sim, vamos iterar:

```
foreach( $groups as $group => $persons ) {

    // Groups

    $groupRow = new Composite\Components\HTML\Row;

    $groupRow -> add( new Composite\Components\HTML\Cell( $group ) );

    $tableGroup -> add( $groupRow );

    // Persons

    foreach( $persons as $person ) {

        $nameCell = new Composite\Components\HTML\Cell( $person['nome'] );
        $dialCell = new Composite\Components\HTML\Cell( $person['ramal'] );

        $personRow = new Composite\Components\HTML\Row;

        $personRow -> add( $nameCell ) -> add( $dialCell );

        $tableGroup -> add( $personRow );
    }
}
```

Primeiro criamos uma linha para o Departamento. Criamos um objeto **Row** e adicionamos nele um objeto **Cell** com o texto devido. Em seguida adicionamos essa primeira composição à tabela anteriormente criada.

Agora vamos iterar a lista de nomes e telefones. Veja que dessa vez fiz de uma forma diferente. Primeiro criei as duas células e atribuí à elas os valores devidos. Só então criei a linha e efetuei a Composição.

Nada me impediria, por exemplo, de fazer assim:

```
$personRow = new Composite\Components\HTML\Row;

$personRow -> add( new Composite\Components\HTML\Cell( $person['nome'] ) )
           -> add( new Composite\Components\HTML\Cell( $person['ramal'] ) );
```

Porém, dessa forma, você engessa o fluxo e impede que as células recebam adereços adicionais (ver abaixo).

Antes de encerrar o loop mais interno, adicionamos a Composição da linha à tabela.

Resta agora renderizar tudo. Fora do loop invocamos o método *Drawable::draw()* no contexto de **Table** e o *AbstractComponent::drawChildren()* nele utilizado vai renderizar tudo de uma vez.

Caso você queira tabelas individuais, uma para cada departamento, basta que a tabela criada em **$tableGroup** seja feita logo no início do primeiro loop e, sua renderização, logo no final.

Outro ponto a ser considerado é o fato de a linha reservada para o nome do Departamento não se estender por toda a largura da tabela.

Isso foi tanto proposital quanto acidental. Proposital para simplificar a implementação desconsiderando quaisquer atributos para os elementos, como no caso, o **colspan** na célula das primeiras linhas.

E acidental porque na hora que escrevi esse código, não lembrava como mesclar células >.<

Mas esse tipo de aprimoramento fica agora por sua conta. Você pode, por exemplo, criar um segundo argumento no construtor de **Cell**, com um array de atributos os quais você inseriria na declaração da TD.

E já que [implode()](http://www.php.net/implode) não trabalha com arrays associativos, pode não parecer, mas [http_build_query()](http://php.net/http_build_query) é fantástico para isso.

Apesar de tudo, vale salientar que, hoje, com as ferramentas de template existentes no mercado, esse tipo de implementação do Composite não é lá muito útil, afinal, é muito mais fácil você abrir e fechar algumas tags PHP e escrever o HTML direto num template, que pode inclusive ser cacheado, do que optar por essa abordagem.

Comment: Apesar de os arquivos no Gist terem me permitido incluir as barras separadoras de diretórios, assim que possível eu edito a resposta para colocar um *sketch* melhorado.

Comment: O que ocorre, no momento que fiz a pergunta, simplifiquei o problema para poder ter auxílio mais facilmente. Quanto a quebrar em camadas, isto foi feito, porém não demonstrei aqui pois utilizo um framework, e desta forma abstrai o problema para focar no algorítimo.