# Controller retornar HTML para View é errado?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Usei essa solução pois ao tentar renderizar uma Tabela numa view com muitos registros o navegador do usuário dava Crash, sei que é uma solução não muito *elegante* mas foi a única solução que me veio em mente. *(Nessa view tenho que carregar todos os registros na tela para o usuário)*

Criei um método **GerarTabela** onde populo com os dados do banco e retorno uma String com HTML contendo os dados. Na chamada da View eu faço uma requisição Ajax que montar a tabela pro usuário, basicamente faço a renderização no server-side.

**Quais as desvantagens de usar esse modelo e qual alternativa poderia ser adotada?** <sup>1</sup>

## Protótipo:

[image: Protótipo]

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Nessa pagina não posso usar paginação, todos os registros devem ser carregados de uma só vez.</sub>

Comment: Essa tabela é apenas para visualização e ações do usuário ou é relacionada a relatórios?

Comment: Para visualização e interação de alguns dos campos. Anexei o protótipo da tela a pergunta para melhor entendimento.

Comment: Com a requisição sendo feita por ajax o navegador está travando?

Comment: Não. Minha View era tipada e recebia uma lista(Fazia uma requisição Ajax também, só que o retorno era uma Lista), com isso eu renderizava utilizando Razor (nesse caso travava). Agora eu faço uma requisição Ajax e dou um innerHTML na tabela (o resultado da minha requisição é o HTML já com os valores populados, responsabilidade do Razor anteriormente).

Comment: Para otimizar esse processo você pode selecionar apenas os campos que vão ser exibidos nessa tabela.

Quanto a parte da view acredito que não faz diferença pois ambos são processados no server-side e com a requisição ajax você tem o beneficio de manter a página respondendo!

Comment: Eu já fazia isso cara, o retorno da minha lista era apenas esses 4 campos que você pode ver no protótipo.

Comment: Quantos registros você está retornando ?

Comment: 4 mil registros.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16781/discussion-between-premiere-and-null).

Comment: A utilização de Ajax não assume que o HTML virá do controller.

Você pode fazer uma request via ajax, exatamente como está fazendo, e ela retornar o HTML exatamente como está fazendo, porém ao invés do controller gerar o html, ele passa para a view renderizar. Uma request com Ajax funciona exatamente como uma request sem ajax, ou seja, pode ter sua própria view e seu js pode escrever o texto diretamente na tela.

Agora se o browser está travando pela quantidade de dados, não sei exatamente como o ajax está auxiliando, a não ser que esteja implementando um esquema de lazy load. É este o caso?

Comment: Seu botão de salvar não está funcionando, fiquei clicando varias vezes e não salvou nada :(

Comment: @RodrigoBorth lol

Comment: @LuísHenrique É porque primeiro eu carrego a página depois faço um requisição que busca uma lista e depois retorna o HTML com todas as tags formatadas, eu só faço a requisição pro Ajax dar um "Append" do HTML na página retornado do Controller.

Comment: Bom, se você diz que melhora, beleza. Mas, de qualquer forma, seu controller não precisa retornar o html. Eu não uso ASP, mas imagino que ele tenha como fazer o que estou dizendo: e se a URL X (de onde vc tira os dados) tivesse um template mais simples contendo apenas a tabela que você precisa? Ela teria uma view, onde o HTML ficaria e você continuaria trabalhando, do ponto de vista da página que requisita os dados, exatamente da mesma forma.

Comment: Cara, eu já tentei isso, antes minha tela tinha apenas a estrutura da tabela e um foreach pro Razor popular os dados que vinham na lista, minha view era tipada, deu pra entender?

Answer (score 16):

Eu utilizaria outra solução.

Motivo: Montar HTML é responsabilidade da View. O Controller deve processar as requisições e executar a lógica (para recuperar informações, alterar o banco de dados, etc...).

Seguindo essa idéia eu não me sentiria bem montando HTML no Controller, não sei se a implementação e manutenção disso ficaria legal, até mesmo pelo fato de não ter usado esse tipo de solução que você escolheu.

**Desvantagem de usar esse modelo:** Uma das premissas do Asp.net Mvc é a separação clara entre sua lógica da negócio de seu código de UI, porém, dependendo da sua implementação, você pode acabar misturando sua lógica de negócio com o HTML que você está gerando no Controller, caminhando um pouco contra essa idéia.

Normalmente quando é necessário carregar muitos registros na View utilizo um [recurso de paginação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23694/pagina%C3%A7%C3%A3o-mvc-asp-net) para não precisar carregar todos os dados.

Já **se eu não pudesse usar paginação**, iria rever/refatorar/repensar o código. **Uma alternativa** seria criar um [**HTML Helper**](http://www.devmedia.com.br/html-helpers-criando-componentes-web-customizados-em-asp-net-mvc/27703) para montar essa tabela por exemplo, mas **não montaria HTML no Controller.**

Comment: No meu caso eu não posso usar paginação, pois o cliente quer que todos os dados sejam carregados na tela sem paginação.

Comment: @NULL Não justifica. Você pode gerar qualquer HTML apenas usando o que está explícito na View. Para paginação: https://www.nuget.org/packages/PagedList/

Comment: @NULL editei a resposta. Se você não pode usar paginação, uma alternativa é criar um HTML Helper, onde ao renderizar a View você chama o HTML Helper criado para renderizar sua tabela.

Comment: Uma exceção à regra é montar o Response Body programaticamente com uma implementação do [Composite](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/31185/250). Bem útil para casos pequenos como verificação de existência de um nome de usuário que não justifica um Template View inteiro (ou ao menos uma interação com uma View Engine) só pra um pseudo-booleano simples.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode ter o mesmo efeito usando uma PartialView. Acredito que, se seu projeto é orientado a objetos, com um Model bem definido, pode ajudar bastante. As _Partials podem ser criadas na mesma pasta de suas Views e você pode adicioná-las com o botão direito sobre a pasta, Add, View e marque o checkbox Create as a partial view.

### Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Detalhar()
{
    var suaLista = _suaBll.Detalhar();
    return PartialView("_Detalhamento", suaLista);
}
```

### PartialView

```
@model SeuNameSpace.ModelDaSuaLista

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>@Html.LabelFor(m => @Model[0].Propriedade)</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in @Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Propriedade)</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

### View

```
<div id="detalhamentoDiv" style="display: none; min-height: 80px;" data-request-url="@Url.Action("Detalhar", "SeuController")"></div>
```

### Javascript

```
var detalhamentoDiv = $("#detalhamentoDiv");
var url = detalhamentoDiv.data('request-url');
detalhamentoDiv.load(url);
detalhamentoDiv.fadeIn(500);
```

Answer (score 0):

Se essa view for apenas visualizada pelo usuário (sem impressão) não aconselho carregar muitos dados, afinal, ele terá que verificar as informações ali. Caso ele queira fazer uma busca bem mais completa, use abas, carregando partes da tabela por vês, assim fica menos bagunçado para o usuário buscar informações...