# Como driblar as tags da table que estão dentro do foreach no PHP e HTML

Tags: php, html, table

Preciso montar uma tabela de dias e eventos. Quando um dos dias do evento for igual ao dia da tabela, ele tem que aparecer na tela no lugar correto. Já estou conseguindo comparar e mostrar, porém, em função da tabela estar toda desmontada por causa do algoritmo que busca e percorre, não consigo fazer com que a tabela fique certa nunca!

Alguém saberia uma solução pra conseguir montar a tabela driblando essas tags?

Segue o código da tabela:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th><center>Turno \ Dia</center></th>
          <?php
            include_once 'classes/semestresclass.php';

            if(!isset($_SESSION)) {session_start();} 

            $idSemestre = $_SESSION['SemestreGeral'];

            $oSemestre = new semestresclass();
            $oSemestre -> listarEdicao($idSemestre);  

            $array = mysql_fetch_array($oSemestre->retorno());

            $start_date = $array['DataDeInicio'];
            $end_date = $array['DataDeTermino'];

            $inicio = new DateTime($start_date);
            $fim = new DateTime($end_date);
            $fim->modify('+1 day');

            $interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
            $periodo = new DatePeriod($inicio, $interval ,$fim);

            foreach($periodo as $data){
                echo '<th><p><center>'.$data->format("d/m/Y").'</p><p>'.$data->format("l").'</p></center></th>';

                include_once 'classes/bancasclass.php';

                if(!isset($_SESSION)) {session_start();}  

                $idSemestre = $_SESSION['SemestreGeral'];

                $oBanca = new bancasclass();
                $oBanca -> listar ($idSemestre);   

                while ($arrayBancas = mysql_fetch_array($oBanca->retorno())){
                    if (date('Y-m-d', strtotime($arrayBancas['dataHora'])) == $data->format('Y-m-d')) {
                       echo '<td>teste</td>';
                    }
                } 
            }
          ?>
    </table>
```

Nesse esquema também vou ter horários pra organizar nessa table... Tô tentando ir por partes, resolver primeiro o dia e depois o horário, mas talvez eu esteja indo pelo caminho errado, talvez eu tenha que já fazer tudo junto... No caso, a primeira coluna da esquerda vai ter os turnos 'manhã', 'tarde' e 'noite' e, dependendo do horário do evento, colocar ele de acordo com os dois eixos.

Eu tô tentando com uma tabela, mas soluções sem tabela também são bem vindas!!

Tabela:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Como a tabela deverá ser apresentada? Do modo como você explicou está meio confuso.

Comment: A ideia era fazer uma tabela como aquela ali que botei como imagem, onde os dados seriam inseridos nos lugares respectivos, de acordo com o dia e horário...

Comment: Não li o código inteiro mas presumo que basta colocar <tr> antes do "while" e </tr> logo no fechamento do mesmo, ainda dentro do "foreach", pois o foreach é o que itera as linhas e, o while itera as colunas. Mas tem coisas sem sentido como o  <tr> aberto lá em cima e não há nenhum fechamento.. Deve fechá-lo antes do foreach.
Esse primeiro <tr></tr> acho que deve ser o cabeçalho, então dentro dele coloque a parte "estática" que é os dias da semana (mon, tue, wed...).

Comment: [Essa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/31185/250), apesar de **parecer** muito a mais daquilo que precisa, pode ser de grande valia para você que, pelo visto, não adotou (ainda?) uma *template engine*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tu tens algumas questões a endereçar para poderes resolver o teu problema. A informação em baixo não vai resolver todo o teu problema, mas visa criar as bases para que consigas lidar com o mesmo:

### Abertura e fecho de tags

Tens que ter alguma atenção à abertura e fecho das tags pois elas tem que ser fechadas na ordem inversa à qual foram abertas:

```php
echo '
<th>
  <p>
    <center>'.$data->format("d/m/Y").'</p>
    <p>'.$data->format("l").'</p>
  </center>
</th>';
```

**Deveria ser:**

```php
echo '
<th>
  <center>
    <p>'.$data->format("d/m/Y").'</p>
    <p>'.$data->format("l").'</p>
  </center>
</th>';
```

A melhor forma é teres sempre o código indentado porque facilita a leitura do mesmo e apercebeste mais rapidamente de problemas como este.

### Ou `<td>` com texto ou `<td>` vazia, mas sempre `<td>`

A *markup* da [`<table>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table) tem que estar presente na sua totalidade salvo algumas exceções onde fazemos uso dos atributos [`colspan`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td#attr-colspan) ou [`rowspan`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td#attr-rowspan). Por este motivo, se tens uma verificação que vai ou não gerar uma [`<td>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td), terás que ter um *fallback* para uma [`<td>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td) vazia para não quebrares o *layout* da tabela:

```
if (date('Y-m-d', strtotime($arrayBancas['dataHora'])) == $data->format('Y-m-d')) {
    echo '<td>teste</td>';
}
```

**Deveria ser:**

```
if (date('Y-m-d', strtotime($arrayBancas['dataHora'])) == $data->format('Y-m-d')) {
    echo '<td>teste</td>';
}
else{
    echo '<td></td>';
}
```

Desta forma, se existir um *match* na data, vai ser enviado para navegador a `<td>teste</td>`, caso não, vai ser enviada uma `<td>` vazia, evitando assim quebrar o *layout* da tabela.

### Output é por linha e não por coluna

Tudo o que tens dentro deste ciclo está a trabalhar como se o output para o navegador fosse por coluna, mas na verdade o output é por linha pois o navegador lê o código de cima para baixo e não da esquerda para a direita:

```
foreach ($periodo as $data) {
  // dados devem ser trabalhados por "row"
}
```

De igual forma, dentro do ciclo em cima, estás a:

- Fazer consecutivamente inclusão do ficheiro `bancasclass.php`;
- Consecutivamente a chamar a função `session_start()`;

Não sei os motivos pelo qual isto acontece, mas o esperado é chamares [`session_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) uma única vez no início do teu ficheiro, salvo se por algo motivo estiveres a destruir a sessão dentro do `bancasclass.php`. De igual forma, o ficheiro `bancasclass.php` deveria ser chamado uma única vez e o código presente no mesmo ser utilizado dentro do ciclo se necessário. Dado o ficheiro chamar-se `...class.php`, assume-se que tem uma [`class`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php).

Por fim, o teu ciclo [`while()`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php) está a enviar `<td>` para o navegador, mas as `<td>` devem estar dentro de uma `<tr>`. Analisando conjuntamente com a imagem que colocaste, é suposto teres 7 (sete) `<td>` dentro de cada `<tr>`, sendo a primeira com o texto "Manhã", "Tarde", ou "Noite"...

Dado tudo isto, e o fato de não sabermos qual o conteúdo do teu ficheiro `bancasclass.php`, assume-se que o mesmo processa dados que dependem diretamente do teu ciclo [`foreach()`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php), sugiro a seguinte adaptação ao código:

```
// Para guardar o HTML do cabeçalho da tabela
$cabecalhosHtml = '';

// Para guardar o HTML das linhas do corpo da tabela
$linhasHtml = '';

foreach ($periodo as $data) {

  /* Processar cabeçalho da coluna
   */
  $cabecalhosHtml.= '
  <th style="text-align:center;">
    '.$data->format("d/m/Y").'
    <br>
    '.$data->format("l").'
  </th>';

  /* Processar celulas da coluna
   */
  include_once 'classes/bancasclass.php';

  if (!isset($_SESSION)) { session_start(); }

  $idSemestre = $_SESSION['SemestreGeral'];

  $oBanca = new bancasclass();
  $oBanca -> listar ($idSemestre);   

  // abrir linha da tabela
  $linhasHtml.= '<tr>';

  // processar celunas da linha
  while ($arrayBancas = mysql_fetch_array($oBanca->retorno())) {

    if (date('Y-m-d', strtotime($arrayBancas['dataHora'])) == $data->format('Y-m-d')) {
      $linhasHtml.= '<td>teste</td>';
    }
    else {
      $linhasHtml.= '<td></td>';
    }
  }

  // fechar linha da tabela
  $linhasHtml.= '</tr>';
}

echo $cabecalhosHtml;
echo $linhasHtml;
```

Answer (score 2):

Tens de ter em atenção todas as tag's da tabela quando imprimes os valores. Pelo que já vi não tens as tag's de forma correta, inspeciona o HTML gerado, no *browser*, e vê o resultado. Vais verificar que te faltam tag's e por isso a tabela não fica direita.

Cada linha da tabela tem de começar com `<tr>` e terminar com `</tr>`, ou seja quando tiveres a imprimir linhas num ciclo `for` tens de imprimir essas tag's sempre que mudas de linha.

Tens aqui um exemplo básico de como podes ter uma tabela:

```html
<table border="1" style="width:300px">
    <thead>   <!-- Inicio do cabeçalho -->
        <tr>    <!-- Inicio de linha     -->
            <th> 
                Nome
            </th>
            <th>
                Sobrenome 
            </th>
            <th>
                Telefone
            </th>
        </tr>   <!-- fechar linha de cabeçalho -->
    </thead>    <!-- fechar cabeçalho          -->
    <tbody>     <!-- inicio do corpo da tabela -->
        <tr>    <!-- Inicio de linha           -->
            <td>
                João
            </td>
            <td>
                Silva
            </td>
            <td>
                912345678
            </td>
        </tr>      <!-- Fim de linha -->
        <tr>
            <td>
                Juliana
            </td>
            <td>
                Sobral
            </td>
            <td>
                912345677
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Total
            </td>
            <td>
                Total
            </td>
            <td>
                Total
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```